# How can I replace something equivalent to PYTHONPATH in the setup file in python?

Tags: python, path, setup.py

I have several packages, each contain a list of python files. One of the package is a test package. Because these files are dependent on each other, I need to do export PYTHONPATH="../package_A/:../package_B/" in the test package.

I wish to write a setup file and replace the need to do PYTHONPATH="../package_A/:../package_B/". The three packages are put in the same top directory, which contains setup.py and myscript:

```
setup(...
scripts = ["myscript"]
...)
```

They also contain MANIFEST and MANIFEST.in. Each package also contains `__init__`, so in package A, `__init__` is `from package B import *`.

After taring and untaring, importing the packages are fine. However, running the test file generates the error message:  `NameError: name 'object in package A' is not defined`. Anything I missed?

Comment: When a python package is "installed" (i.e., in lib/pythonx.x/site-packages) then you do not need to alter `PYTHONPATH` to import it. Just say `from spam import eggs`. Also, if your package A is importing _everything_ in package B, it might be simpler to merge them into a single package.

Comment: that is what I did. What I don't understand is why `from package A import *` does not generate an error, and a few lines later, when an object class in A is used, `c = package_A_object()`, generates an error?

Comment: `from module import *` doesn't import everything - some things are excluded (for example, names beginning with an underscore). I would assume that if you import the relevant name directly (rather than using the * import), you will have more luck. If you post the relevant code, then it will be much easier to track down the issues.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I found that it is a naming error due to that the file happens to have the same name as package A, so `from package A.filename import class c` works.